# Avoiding non-crossplatform dependencies in .Net Standard

Tags: c#, cross-platform, .net-standard

I'm porting the existing library from .Net Framework 4.7.2 to .Net Standard 2.0 to make it cross-platform but still retain compatibility with .Net Framework apps.

I do not understand how to **avoid non-cross-platform dependencies**.

**My library** uses **dynamic types** and **Settings.Designer.cs.**

To support it in .Net Standard, I have to add a *reference* to `Microsoft.CSharp` and `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` NuGet packages, which in turn adds dependencies to some other packages like `System.Security.Principal.Windows`, even though I don't use any security-related code.

The last two are clearly part of [Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility) package.

[image: NuGet dependencies]

1. How to find out, if these dependencies are **cross-platform** or not (i.e. part of Windows Platform Extensions)?

When I go to [.NET API Browser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/dotnet/api/) I see that `Microsoft.Csharp` is not in .Net Standard 2.0, however it is in .Net Platform Extensions 2.1 and further. Does it mean, that this package is not cross-platform? Are there any other services to check platform support for NuGet packages?

[image: .NEt API results]

2. When I created a simple test app on .Net Core 2.1 that uses my library and published it to a Linux platform with `dotnet publish -c Release --self-contained true --runtime linux-x64`, the app actually works fine on Linux machine. Does it mean, that my lib is fully cross-platform and I can safely use it in production, or I may still encounter `System.PlatformNotSupportedException` on Linux in the future?